Are there EU consumer protections on annual subscription renewals for digital content?
A year ago I had subscribed on an annual basis to an expensive online platform based in Portugal. I used it a few times in the first 6 months, found it the information provided to be inaccurate and unhelpful, and ended up forgetting about it entirely. A year after my original subscription date, I got hit with the renewal bill.
I immediately (in fewer than 12 hours) wrote to the company and explained that I didn't wish to renew and requested a refund. They have denied my refund, explaining that I should have canceled in advance.
They claim that they emailed me, once, a week prior, to warn me of the pending renewal. I did not receive this email.
I believe this is different than the "free trial conversion" case of online subscriptions. I paid for the first year in which the services were used, but simply don't wish to continue since the service doesn't live up to its claims. Am I correct? Do I have any protection according to EU consumer law here?

As to the question in the subject line, yes, there are consumer protections. They may not be relevant in your case as specified in the body of your question, if you did indeed 'forget' to cancel in time and if they made no error. The consumer protections affect

price clarity and 'pre-checked' boxes,
a 14-day cancellation period after the initial subscription,
the availablility and ease of use of online cancellation.

As I understand it, some member states go beyond EU law in their implementaton.

Your Contract Prevails
Your contract contains how and when you can cancel it, and when a contract renewal happens. Unless the contract contains a grace period, you are bound by the contract.

It states that I'll receive an advance notice of the charge, which I did not.

Did you check your SPAM inbox?
